# Hedging a binary option close to expiry

Tags: options, delta-hedging, binary

I have been asked to prove mathematically that a binary option close to maturity should be hedged using a call spread with the same maturity.

I understand that far from maturity, one would use delta hedging to sell or purchase the underlying asset. Yet as time to expiry tends to zero the delta profile tends towards a dirac delta function and so renders the hedge impractical.
See: [delta of a binary option](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/23267/delta-of-binary-option/23272)

Other than calculus to derive delta, are there any other rigorous ways to construct hedges of this kind?

As this is a homework question, hints rather than full answers are most welcome.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: I think the intuition here is that a call spread has similar payoff to a binary option if the two strikes are close enough. But in general coming up with such approximations would seem to be an open ended process requiring some cleverness, not a rigorous algorithm afaik. You have to ask 'what do I already know that is similar to this'.

Comment: Well, if you write the value of an non-path dependent option as being equal to the (discounted) expected value of the payoff at maturity using a risk neutral density and combine this with the Breeden-Litzernberger formula, then you can write it's value as an (infinite) combination of calls and puts. So if you pick a distance between call strikes, discretizing can't be too hard?

Comment: Also, for hints, google for static replication

Comment: Brief overiew of Static Replication here https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjO1-zO4rXSAhWC1RoKHehmB8cQFghIMAc&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.springer.com%2Fcda%2Fcontent%2Fdocument%2Fcda_downloaddocument%2F9783642221545-c1.pdf%3FSGWID%3D0-0-45-1188759-p174129368&usg=AFQjCNEM4s5J2t1C8bcgAji0GrvG058ysA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point here is that when **close to maturity** a binary option should be hedged with a call spread.

Note that, for a binary option with a payoff at maturity $T$ of the form $\mathbb{1}_{S_T>K}$, the value at time $0\le t < T$ is given by
$$e^{-r(T-t)}N(d_2), $$
where $$d_2 = \frac{\ln \frac{S_t}{K}+(r-\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}.$$
Since
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial N(d_2)}{\partial S_t} = \frac{\phi(d_2)}{\sigma S_t \sqrt{T-t}}\rightarrow \infty,
\end{align*}
as $t\rightarrow T$, the delta based hedging is not applicable.

However, with a call spread approximation of the form
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{1}_{S_T>K} \approx \frac{1}{\varepsilon}\Big[\big(S_T-(K-\varepsilon)\big)^+ - \big(S_T-K\big)^+\Big].
\end{align*}
The delta at time $0\le t < T$ is given by
$$\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\big[N(d_1^{-\varepsilon})-N(d_1^0)\big], $$
which is finite as $t\rightarrow T$. Here, 
\begin{align*}
d_1^{\alpha} = \frac{\ln \frac{S_t}{K+\alpha}+(r+\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2)(T-t)}{\sigma\sqrt{T-t}}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Do you know of a reference that derives the call spread delta from the pricing equation rather than by deducing it from the gradient of the payoff profile?

Comment: @NickWilton: I do not have a reference. The delta for a call spread is derived from the pricing formula rather than the payoff profile, by noting that the delta of a vanilla call is of the form $N(d_1)$.